# Roots of the equation $e^{x-1}+x-2=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is:

> Find the real roots of the equation 
>   $$e^{x-1}+x-2=0$$

By observation I found out that $x=1$ is a root, but I'm not sure whether there are anymore roots.

How do I check for any other roots?

Comment: You could graph the function $f(x) = e^{x-1}+x-2$. What do you learn from that?

Comment: This happens to be a question from an exam, so I was thinking about using the mean value theorem. I'm not sure how to apply it. Is there no other way without graphing the function?

Comment: If a function is monotonic it can have at most one real root. This means $f'(x)>0 (<0)$. By reverse of Rolle's Th. Since $f'(x) \ne 0$, so $f(x)=0$ can have atmost one root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting $f(x)=e^{x-1}+x-2$, we see that $f'(x)=e^{x-1} + 1 > 0$, so that $f$ is monotonically increasing...

Comment: I did not think about that, thank you! Is there a way to solve this question using the mean value theorem?

Comment: @ExtremeRaider the monotone increasingness follows from the mean value theorem....

Comment: Nevermind my earlier comment, I did not think about it before asking. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: The function $x \mapsto e^{x-1}+x-2$ is monotonic.